# Как получить объект User в Spring REST API

Tags: spring, spring-security

При авторизации пользователя в системе с помощью SpringSecurity в сессию ложится объект UserDTO, содержащий все данные о пользователе.

Вопрос состоит в том, что можно ли как-то получить доступ к этому объекту из Spring Rest сервиса, к которому обращается этот пользователь, если учитывать, что это происходит внутри одной jvm.

Comment: Не очень ясно что именно вам нужно. Вы хотите сделать такой запрос, который в ответе будет эту модель иметь или при обработке входящего запроса на сервере получить эту модель в обрабатывающем запрос коде?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, при аутентификации пользователя я делаю request.getSession().setAttribute("user", userDTO); как его получить в сервисе?

Comment: В каком сервисе? Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795626/3212712

Comment: request.getSession().getAttribute("user");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вытащить из контекста безопасности

```
Optional<UserDTO> company = Optional
                              .ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                              .map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication())
                              .map(auth -> auth.getPrincipal())
                              .filter(p -> p instanceof UserDTO)
                              .map(u -> ((UserDTO) u));
```

Или добавить в метод контроллера аргумент типа `Principal` и Spring его внедрит сам

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some-path")
public class SomeController {
    @GetMapping
    public SomeClass getSomeClass(Principal principal) {
        if (prinicpal instanceof UserDTO)
            UserDTO user = (UserDTO) principal;
        ...
    }
}
```